# Dart: web vs web/src

Tags: dart, project-structure

I just read [Dart's recommended package layout](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html) and am confused on one thing: what content goes in the `web` package, and what content goes in `web/src`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package layout recommendation doesn't include anything about `web/src` only `lib/src` as far as I have seen.
But as it is convention in lib to separate between public and private API many do the same in web.
AFAIK in web you can use any sub folders you like.